# ClientMembership doesn't implement abstract member

Tags: c#, inheritance, authorization, visual-studio-2013

I have this error that shows up (there are 2 actually but regarding this part of the code)

1. 'MyApplication.Authorization.ClientMembership' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.FindUsersByName(string, int, int, out int)'
2. 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.FindUsersByName(string, int, int, out int)': no suitable method found to override.

And the code I use is this one:

```
public class ClientMembership : ExtendedMembershipProvider
{
    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        MyApplication.Models.User usr = new MyApplication.Models.User();
        return usr.ValidareCredential(username, password);
    }
    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUserByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I don't know what to do. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Read the second error more carefully.

Comment: I edited now. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, you need to implement `FindUsersByName()`.
Your `FindUserByName()` is missing an `s`.

Comment: Nice! I did that and now I get this error 

    Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyApplication.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Comment: I mean it in the way that when I run the project this is what I get in the browser. I saw something on this site about this but it doesn't help me because the Gloabl.asax.cs is ok and so is the Markup.